# How to verify size and content of the collection in JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, spring-boot, junit

I am new to this and have a JSON String returned with an array in it like the following in a Java SpringBoot application.

{... "downlineLevels": ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07"] }

Only the following JUnit tests are successful.

1) .andExpect(jsonPath("$.downlineLevels", hasSize(1)))

I was expecting hasSize(7)

2) .andExpect(jsonPath("$.downlineLevels.[0]", is("01")))

I cannot do $.downlineLevels.[1]. So how can I check all the members.

Comment: What language and library are using?

Comment: It is Java SpringBoot and Junit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. The JUnit test was pointing to a different database using another properties file. Sorry for the confusion.